# Custom Keyboard extension with UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, custom-keyboard, textdocumentproxy

I have custom keyboard extension with UITextField in it. I am able switch to `UITextField`'s text input, but cannot switch back to `self.textDocumentProxy`. Does anybody know, how to do something like `[self.textDocumentProxy becomeFirstResponder]`?

(By the way, it looks like "GIF Keyboard" app provides such possibility)

Comment: just a question: I guess it's not possible launch the 'default' iOS keyboard recursively from within the extension is it? .-.

Comment: Hello. I know this is old question but may I know how you switch `UITextField` input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've implemented next workaround for this:

1. My `textFied` inherits from `UITextField`. `UserInteraction` disabled to prevent it from `becomeFirstResponder` (because you are not able switch back to system input). I've added blinking `UIView` as cursor imitation ([blinking animation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1480476/1010644)). Change this cursor `origin.x` in overwrited `setText:` method by calculating length of current string (use `boundingRectWithSize:` method for this).
2. When user types something I am checking if `textField` is active (showed) and then adding/removing symbols to `textField` (with `setText:`) or `self.textDocumentProxy` `insertText:`/`deleteBackward` methods accordingly.